# Access FragmentActivity within Class extends by DialogFragment

Tags: android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I have a class which **extends** by `DialogFragment`. I want to call a method in a class which **extends** by `FragmentActivity` within this `DialogFragment`.

In my `FragmentActivity`, i do as below to call `DialogFragment`.

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragmentClass();
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

I'm using this `DialogFragment` to show a `DatePicker`. When user select date and click **set** button, i want to call a method in my `FragmentActivity`.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

EditText mEdit;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mEdit.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
}
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
}
```

}

// import necessary packages...